# Checkstyle conflicting with Oracle Java Style Guide

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'm taking a course that is requiring the use of Checkstyle. I'm quite confused about the "conventions" it seems to be enforcing.

For example:

```
/**
 * Something, something.
 *                        <-- NOT ALLOWED
 * @param bla bla bla
 */
```

The ternary operator is not allowed at all and braces are required on every if statement.

These "conventions" seem to be in conflict with the Oracle style guidlines: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

I get that there are almost as many ideas about style guidelines as there are programmers, but where did this set of rules come from and is there some particular advantage to the Checkstyle rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check with the course coordinators to make sure that you are using the correct Checkstyle ruleset.  If you are, then you need to ask **them** why they've chose a ruleset with those particular restrictions.

But the bottom line is that there are many opinions on Java style and layout, and you'll just have to live with the rules that are imposed on you by your course ... and in future, by your project manager, etcetera.

---

I can see arguments for those particular example rules:

- The blank line in the javadoc is a waste of screen space
- The ternary operator tends to be used in places that make code less readable.
- A discipline of always using '{' '}' with `if` statements and loop bodies avoids the scenario where bugs that are obscured by inconsistent indentation.  (With the braces in place, the inconsistency is more obvious.)